# Is there an API call to disable the network for Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, real-time

I'm maintaining code on a real-time system running Red Had Enterprise Linux. I'm afraid that sometimes, despite running things at the highest priority, the network manages to slow the computer down, and I would like to disable the card so that I have the full power of the CPU at my disposal. I need some files at the beginning of my function from the network, but after a certain point, I can effectively disable the network until the program is complete. Is there a way I could disable the network through some sort of an API call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully someone could expand on this, but it may be worthwhile to look into how ifconfig disables network devices. You probably can do an ioctl on the interface to disable it. Depending on the driver / nic, the kernel may then be able to cause the network hardware to drop packets instead of the cpu.

The source code for ifconfig is here:

http://net-tools.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=net-tools/net-tools;a=blob;f=ifconfig.c;h=be6999578bd81e91e90e26a35fad91f4928f4226;hb=HEAD

Iproute2, which also is able to do the same things as ifconfig is described here:

http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git;a=blob;f=ip/iplink.c;h=6b051b65faab72ea46534ad33f71b3f6cd35c11b;hb=HEAD#l589

I found the source code of iproute2 slightly easier to understand than ifconfig, but it should be relatively easy to see how they interface with the networking stack to disable an interface.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I tend to live on RHEL5 most of the time. So it's certainly possible that ifconfig has become obsolete. I'd be surprised if the method they used to interact with the kernel has also become obsolete though.

Comment: @sharth: the SIOCSIFFLAGS ioctl and friends ARE obsolete. The main missing functionality is the lack of multiple IP per interface support (without hacks like interface aliases). There is also plenty of others options in the rtnetlink ("netlink route") interfaces. Why ? Just because it's extensible.

Comment: iproute2 appears to also use the ioctl. [link](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git;a=blob;f=ip/iplink.c;h=6b051b65faab72ea46534ad33f71b3f6cd35c11b;hb=HEAD#l589). If you have example code that uses a more up to date technology, please either edit my answer, or post one with those tools. I can only post what I know.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Also, apparently RHEL5 has the ip-route tools. I've just always used the ifconfig command. Good to know what is the newer stuff though.

Answer (score 1):

The way the system does it is by issuing `ip link set dev ${DEVICE} down 2> null` . Looking at the code of ip.c , e.g. [here](http://www.koders.com/c/fid3E2D384D105BAECD6307F7B68C21519EE470A3C9.aspx?s=ip.c#L233) you can check for yourself how it is done. The key is the [netif.h](http://koders.com/c/fidCE0716C90860EFB89F087DD042B7B7CD048949C3.aspx?s=netif.h#L43) that shuts down the network by calling `net_if_set_down()` . I think it just sets a flag.

```
netif->flags &= ~NETIF_FLAG_UP
```

You can go on from here on your own, but keep in mind netif.h is part of the kernel...

Answer (score 0):

The networking is part of the kernel, rather than a user space process. You could do the equivalent of calling `rmmod` to remove the network driver module from the kernel, assuming you have module support enabled; or you could just set all the netfilter rules to `DROP` and see if that speeds things up. I'd probably prefer to do that in a launcher script (using the ready-made `iptables-save`/`iptables-restore`) rather than coding that in C++. Or you could even just bring the interfaces down.

Comment: setting all netfilters rules to DROP will likely slows things down. It would be better to just down the interface (assuming that networking causes the problem).

Answer (score -2):

You said "API" but did not mention the language of your program/script, nor your OS.

On Linux variants like CentOS, RHEL, SuSE, and Fedora, from a bash/Bourne shell script:

```
/sbin/service network stop
rc=$?
if [ "$rc" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "***** Failed to stop networking service"
    exit $rc
fi
# Do your thing
/sbin/service network start
```